# How to generate a password from given string and length in VB

Tags: string, vb.net

I want to generate a fixed password based from a given string (a clue) with a certain length.
For example, from the word 'school' and '10' character length, I would like to generate a fixed password, lets say 'ihskm28s9a'. So everytime I entered the cue word and the length, it will always gives me a fixed results, which is 'ihskm28s9a', not generated all over again.
I am nubie in programming so I choose VB as my my starter language since easier for me to understand it.

Thank you very much and sorry if I said something badly.

Comment: Google "hashing functions" - take the first 10 characters of the hashed cue word.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Consider using one of the hashing classes in [`System.Security.Cryptography`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.security.cryptography(v=vs.110).aspx) to generate your hash string. Search also on [StackOverflow](http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bvb.net%5D+sha1).

Comment: Thank you for the comment, I will google it.. Thank you

Comment: I saw the function and indeed provide a fixed value and it also being used as a file identifier after being copied. But, can i limit and set the length of the generated results? For example with the same input, 'school', is hashing will give a different results if the length given is different as well? For example, lentgh '10' characters, against '9' character.

Comment: They are saying choose a hash which will give out (large) N characters, then for n < N just take the first n characters.

Comment: @Raymond just hash the input with the length concatenated together.